# My onReadyStateChange is never called,why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

my code is simple.

```
function useXMLHttpRequest() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.ashx", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.onReadyStateChange = function () {
    alert("ss");
};
xmlhttp.send("i=5");
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

}

when I call useXMLHttpRequest.Yes ,it alerts the xmlhttp.responseText's value. but it doesn't alert("ss"). Both in IE9 and firefox.
Anyone can tell me what's worng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript (and all other languages that I know of) are case-sensitive, so [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) is not the same as `onReadyStateChange`.

Try this instead:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert("ss");
};
```

Comment: yes,i found this problem after i post this question.What a foolish me.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.ashx", false);
```

3rd parameter is `false`, which means that you are using synchronous request. For such requests onreadystatechange does not work and is discouraged to use it. Anyway, your request will not go further until complete completion, so `alert(xmlhttp.responseText);` immediately after `xmlhttp.send("i=5");` works correctly and there is no need to handle request state change event.

See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_httprequest.asp).